# CakePHP's Mocking model not working as expected

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to write my first unit test in cakePHP.
I would like to try it out with the following action:

```
public function joinLobby($userId = null, $lobbyId = null) {
    // json webservice layout
    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    if (!$userId || !$lobbyId) {
        throw new CakeException(__('Paramter(s) missing'));
    }
    if (!$this->Lobby->exists($lobbyId)) {
        throw new CakeException(__('Invalid lobby supplied'));
    }
    if (!$this->User->exists($userId)) {
        throw new CakeException(__('Invalid user supplied'));
    }

    $this->__addUsersToLobby(array($userId), $lobbyId);
}
```

And my test case goes like this so far:

```
public function testShouldNotAddNonExistentUserToLobby() {
    $this->LobbiesController = $this->generate('Lobbies', array(
        'methods' => array(
            'joinLobby',
            '__addUsersToLobby'
        ),
        'models' => array(
            'Lobby',
            'User'
        )
    ));
    $this->LobbiesController->Lobby->expects($this->any())->method('exists')->will($this->returnValue(true));
    $this->LobbiesController->User->expects($this->once())->method('exists')->will($this->returnValue(false));
    $this->LobbiesController->expects($this->never())->method('__addUsersToLobby');
    $this->testAction('Lobbies/joinLobby/1/1');
}
```

When I run my test, I get this:

UsersLobbiesControllerTest::testShouldNotAddNonExistentUserToLobby
Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

The only way I can get the test to pass is by changing both "$this->once()" to "$this->any()" or "$this->never()".

Any help??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to make it work.
The problem was that I was mocking the same function I was testing, so it wasn't actually called. Therefore, the code that called the other functions wasn't executed.
Removing 'joinLobby' from the 'methods' array made the work.

Cheers